# how to use lapply in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use `lapply` so that I can apply a custom function on all elements of a vector in R. I am trying to avoid using `for` loop here .

This is what I have so far:

```
writeToHDFS <- function(fileName){
  print(fileName)
  hdfs.init()
 modelfile <- hdfs.file(fileName, "w")
  hdfs.write(gaDataUser, modelfile)
 hdfs.close(modelfile)
}

fileNames <- c("gaDataUser", "gaDataSession", "gaDataSources","gaDataEventTracking", "gaDataEcommerce", "gaDataEcommerce2", "gaDataEcommerce3", "gaDataEcommerce4")


lapply(fileNames,writeToHDFS(x))
```

I have variables with the names mentioned in the character vector `fileNames`.

**What I need to know:**

1. How to pass each string from the vector `fileNames` to function `writeToHDFS` since I would like this function to be executed for every element in the vector.
2. How to use string name to access variables of that name in the function. 
   For example:

At this line,I have to access variable with name same as string passed to `fileName` variable in the function.

```
hdfs.write(variableWithData, modelfile)
```

3. Can I pass the variable `fileName` to

```
modelfile <- hdfs.file(fileName, "w")
```

instead of passing a string for file name ?

Comment: I am pretty amazed with how R community on stack overflow down votes pretty much everything.

Comment: Please read the documentation `?lapply`, look at the examples `example(lapply)` (both are outside resources for SO). Read the great http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega to get an idea how lapply/sapply works. For geting an object from a charater look at `get()`

Comment: `a <- "BOD"; x <- get(a); x`

Comment: Thank @jogo. That helped

Comment: The problem to me seems to be: `lapply(fileNames, writeToHDFS(x))`.  The second argument should be the function only: `lapply(fileNames, writeToHDFS)`.  R can pass functions as objects to other functions such as `lapply`.

Comment: @Bazz: That indeed was the problem but how does it pass the current iterable object to the function when not defined inline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to use lapply so that I can apply a custom function on all elements of a vector in R

In this situation, you should use `tapply`:

```
tapply(fileNames, 1:length(fileNames), writeToHDFS)
```

`lapply`, is short for "list-apply", but `fileNames` is a vector not a list.

Since you are already pretty well-aimed at using `lapply`, you can learn from `?lapply`.

Comment: `lapply()` can be applied to a vector: `lapply(1:5, sqrt)`

Answer (score 1):

writeToHDFS(x) gives you return value of function.
But you want to pass function so:

```
lapply(fileNames,writeToHDFS)
```

Comment: But that throws an error:lapply(fileNames,writeToHDFS(x))
Error in print(fileName) : object 'x' not found

Comment: @SimranKaur that is not true.